# In-app purchase for PWA - Google play store and Apple store

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store, progressive-web-apps

I am new to PWA development, starting to build a PWA using React JS and want to integrate in-app purchase functionality for few feature of PWA. I have seen lots of articles but couldn`t get anything useful. Since I will be deploying my PWA to both Google App store and Apple app store, need pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with google payment API, below link provides you details on how you can integrate PWA with payment API.

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-the-payment-request-api

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @daydreamer try this https://web.dev/how-payment-request-api-works/#payment-request-api

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much exactly the reason for https://overhide.io.

Simple Web components to add login and in-app purchases (IAPs) to any Web app.  Logins include social, Ethereum, or bitcoin.  Payments can be in dollars or cryptos.

The quick demos:  https://github.com/overhide/overhide-widgets#demos

There is a React.js version of the demo (integration):  https://github.com/overhide/overhide-widgets-react-demo-app

Disclosure:  I'm deeply involved in this OSS project.